# aggrid valueGetter/valueSetter out of components scope

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display and edit some backend data.
Because the values are stored as an enum, I want to convert the enum number to an nice display text and make the options avaible over a select element.

For this I am using following column def:

```js
columnDefs = [
   {    
      valueGetter: this.stringifyType,
      valueSetter: this.setType,
      colId: 'typCol',
      headerName: 'Type',
      editable: true,
      cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
      cellEditorParams: { values: this.arrTypMapping },
  }
```

if I got that right, the `agSelectCellEditor` accecpts only an array of strings for the values. To make this work I created the valueGetter and valueSetter functions. Which converts the database integer value into the pretty display text and reverse. This works fine so far.

Here is my problem, inside the the getter / setter function I cannot access any objects of my angular component. Obviously the aggrid runs those functions out of the components scope.
Is it somehow possible to access the objects of my component inside those getter/setter functions?

Thanks for your help!

rick

Comment: You can make a service, send the values in the service and inject the service where the value is needed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggrid allow to pass some context to configuration object and later you can use it in cells for example. Simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-share-component-context?)! :)